# Probability of sum greater than 1

Tags: probability

In the complex plane, let u,v be two distinct solutions of z^2019 − 1 = 0. Find the probability that |u + v| ≥ 1.

I know that it's probability should be done by integration but am not being able to proceed help!

Comment: I'd say *by geometry* rather than "by integration".

Comment: Can you please elaborate your solution

Comment: Presumably you're assuming here that the pair $\left(u, v\right)$ is chosen "randomly"  from among the $2019\choose2$ pairs of distinct roots of the polynomial $z^{2019} - 1$ (i.e. with every pair having an equal probability of being chosen).  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes then how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots are $\xi_k : =e^{i 2 \pi k / 2019}$ for $k = 0, \ldots, 2018$.

$|\xi_j+\xi_k| \ge 1$ is equivalent to $$|\xi_j|^2 + |\xi_k|^2 + \overline{\xi_j} \xi_k + \overline{\xi_k} \xi_j \ge 1.$$
Since $|\xi_j|=|\xi_k|=1$, this is equivalent to $$- 1/2 \le \overline{\xi_j} \xi_k + \overline{\xi_k} \xi_j = e^{i 2 \pi (k-j)/2019} + e^{i 2 \pi (j - k)/2019} = 2 \cos(2 \pi (k-j) / 2019).$$
Use this to derive a sufficient and necessary condition on $k$ and $j$ for $|\xi_j + \xi_k| \ge 1$.

Comment: @angyavian extending your answer, by symmetry, one can assume WLOG, that j=0.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Viewing $u, v$ as unit vectors on the Argard diagrams. 
$$|u+v| \ge 1$$
is equivalent to

$$|u|^2+|v|^2+2\langle u, v\rangle \ge 1$$

Comment: I have also got upto this but a complete solution will be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $u = e^{i\theta}$ , then for what range of values of $\phi$ is $ \left| u + e^{i\left(\theta +\phi\right) }\right| \ge 1 $ ? If $\theta = 0$ (i.e. $u = 1$) then for how many values of $j$ does $\frac{2j\pi}{2019}$ lie within this range ? If $\theta = \frac{2k\pi}{2019}$ , then for how many values of $j$ does $\frac{2j\pi}{2019}$ lie within the range ? Does the answer depend on the value of $k$ ?